# Adding a WCF Tcp.net service to IIS for Visual Studio 2013 and how to test it

Tags: wcf, iis, tcp

I am trying to deploy a wcf service I have created in Visual studio.
I am almost positive it is a configuration issue in either the wcf service config or in IIS itself.

The config I am using in the service is as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CandidateServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500" maxConcurrentInstances="500" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="SurveyService.SurveyService" behaviorConfiguration="CandidateServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="/Survey/SurveyService" binding="netTcpBinding" name="CandidateServiceEndPoint" contract="Prometric.Census.SurveyService.ISurveyService" />
    <endpoint address="/Survey/SurveyService/mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I deployed the service once from visual Studio and pointed a new site on IIS with the following settings pointing to the deployment folder

[image]

Then after this within IIS you can see the site is in an unknown status:

[image]

It is from here that I can't connect to the service or find if it is running or not. I have tried the command /an : find /i "9015" and found nothing so I assume the service is not even running.

If I where to change the bindings on the WCF service and IIS to use http instead everything works fine. (Should say using http is not an option)

Also on top of not getting the service up and running I'm unsure how to test the service as TCP, Am I able to just add a service reference as you would with a http sefvice? As you can see I am pretty new to the tcp side of things and if I have left out any vital information please let me know so I can inslude it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you :

https://rohitguptablog.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/configuring-wcf-service-with-nettcpbinding/

I followed this guide to make a net.tcp wcf service and it went smoothly. Also, are you sure that your folder has the required privileges? It can be tricky to use another folder than wwwroot/inetpub